# How to get the details of DeclRefExpr from VarDecl in clang?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-ast-matchers

My ast node looks like this:

|-VarDecl 0x158f5190 <line:7:1, col:14> col:6 used ptr1 'int *' cinit

| |-UnaryOperator 0x158f62c0 <col:13, col:14> 'int *' prefix '&' cannot overflow

| | `-DeclRefExpr 0x158f62a0 col:14 'int' lvalue Var 0x158f50f0 'foo' 'int'

How can I get the address and name of 'foo' from VarDecl?

I have used DeclContext::decl_iterator to iterate through all the nodes and I can dump the entire VarDecl. I am interested in extracting information from DeclRefExpr with VarDecl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getNameAsString` to get the name of declaration.

If you are writing something like LibTooling so it's better to use [MatchFinder](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) for searching and matching nodes in AST. For example:

```
varDecl(hasDescendant(
     declRefExpr( ... ).bind("found DeclRefExpr!!!")))
```

And write a [MatchCallback](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ast__matchers_1_1MatchFinder_1_1MatchCallback.html) to manipulate the found results.